# Regarding "Sterntalers", related to the basis of a topology.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Exercise.** A "Sterntaler" S is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which has the following two properties:

$\hspace{2cm} (i)$ $0 \in S$

$\hspace{2cm} (ii)$ $rx \in S, \forall x \in S \text{ and } r \in [0,1]$

For any open Sterntaler $S$, define $S_\epsilon(x) = \{x + \epsilon y: y \in S\}$, $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $\epsilon > 0$. Show that this sets form a basis for the Euclidian topology.

**My attempt.** Firsly, we prove that $\forall x \in \Bbb R^n, \exists A \in S_\epsilon: x \in A$. To do so, it suffices to take $A = S_\epsilon(x)$ since $x \in S_\epsilon(x)$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ (by definition of a sterntaler, $0 \in S$ and so, all we have to do is take the case where $y=0$). Secondly, we have to prove the following:
\begin{equation*}
\text{ If }x \in A_1 \cap A_2 \Rightarrow x \in A_3 \subseteq A_1 \cap A_2, \text{ where } A_i \in S_\epsilon, \quad \forall i \in [3]
\end{equation*}
I am having some trouble doing this part of the problem, and I feel like it is majorly because I am having trouble identifying the diferent sets $S_\epsilon$ we can have. For example, to prove what's wanted, I would assume there is a $x$ in both $A_1$ and $A_2$, but I am having trouble defining the equatioons for $A_1$ and $A_2$, i.e., we will have different $x's$ (in the original definition), different $y's$ and different $\epsilon's$? Any help would be apreciatted.

Comment: limited = bounded? Is the word "Sterntaler" used in a textbook or in a lecture? It is a German word which has a *single occurence* - in the Brother Grimm's fairy tale "Die Sterntaler" (The Star Money).

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, limited = bounded, sorry for the mistake. It is indeed a german word, my professor has german roots and I guess that's where it came from... I have never heard of it in any of his lectures. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From your attempt, you seem to be proving that the sets $S_\epsilon(x)$ form a basis for **some** topology. But the exercise asks you to prove that they form a basis for the Euclidean topology. What you need to show is that every open set in Euclidean topology can be written as a union of some $S_\epsilon(x)$.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: I think your definition of Sterntaler is very close to that of a star domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks for your comment. So, the correct aproach would be to take any $\mathcal{B}_r(x) = \{y \in \Bbb R^n : d(x,y) < r\}$ and prove this set can be written as a finite union of some $S_\epsilon(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, except that it need not be a finite union: can be any union.

Comment: Here is how I would visualize it in $\Bbb R$, for starters. In $\Bbb R$, the sets $S_\epsilon(x) = \{x + \epsilon y : y \in S\}$ would correspond to sets of the form $[x,x+\epsilon y']$, where $y' = \max_{y \in S} y$, or, alternatively, to sets of the form $[x+\epsilon y'',x]$, if $\max_{y \in S}y < 0$. Let's consider now any open interval ( let this be $(a,b)$)on $\Bbb R$ (these are the open sets of $\Bbb R$).  So, \begin{equation*} (a,b) = S_\epsilon(a) \cup S'_\epsilon(b) , \end{equation*} where $\max_{y \in S} y > 0$ and $\max_{y \in S'}y < 0$ and also $b + \epsilon y'' = a + \epsilon y'$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Is my aproach to the $\Bbb R$ case right? And how would one extend this to $\Bbb R^n$? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt you try to show that the $S_\epsilon(x)$ form a basis for **some** topology on $\mathbb R^n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)), section  "Definition and basic properties".

But this is not what you are required to do. You must prove that these sets from a basis for the *Euclidean topology*. This means that you must prove the following:

1. The $S_\epsilon(x)$ are open in the Euclidean topology.
2. For each (Euclidean) open subset $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ and each $\xi \in U$ there exists some $S_\epsilon(x)$ such that $\xi \in S_\epsilon(x) \subset U$.

For notation, let $B_d(c) = \{ a \in \mathbb R^n \mid \lVert a - c \rVert < d \}$ denote the open Euclidean ball with center $c$ and radius $d$.

Note that $S$ is a **single fixed** Sterntaler which is required to be *open*, i.e. open  in the Euclidean topology. Since $S$ is bounded, we have $S \subset B_R(0)$ for some $R > 0$.

Proof of 1. The maps $\mu_\epsilon : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, \mu_\epsilon(a) = \epsilon a$,and $\tau_x :  \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, \tau_x(b) = x + b$, are homeomorphisms. Hence $\tau_x(\mu_\epsilon(S))$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. But $S_\epsilon(x) = \tau_x(\mu_\epsilon(S))$.

Proof of 2. Let $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open and $\xi \in U$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r(\xi) \subset U$. Let $\epsilon = r/R$. Obviously $\xi \in S_\epsilon(\xi)$ because $0 \in S$. We claim that $S_\epsilon(\xi) \subset B_r(\xi)$ which finishes the proof. Consider any element of $\eta \in S_\epsilon(\xi)$. It has the form $\eta = \xi + \epsilon y$ with $y \in S$. We have $\lVert \eta - \xi \rVert = \lVert \epsilon y \rVert = \epsilon \lVert y \rVert < \epsilon R = r$, thus $\eta \in B_r(\xi)$.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense to me! Can you just clarify the step that allows us to conclude $\tau_x(\mu_\epsilon (S))$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$ (in the proof of $1.$) ?

Comment: @Seabourn Do you see that $\mu_\epsilon$ and $\tau_x$ are homeomorphisms?

Comment: Yes! By definition, they are obviously bijective, contínuous and have an inverse function that's also contínuous.

Comment: Does that help seeing what I mentioned?

Comment: Under homeomorphisms images of open sets are *open*, thus $\tau_x(\mu_\epsilon(S))$ is open because $S$ is open.